# How to create event listeners for server-side React?

Tags: reactjs, server-side

I am developing an application that requires an event listener. The function supplied to this event listener is interacting with the DOM. The same function also needs to run when the component has mounted:

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.getWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWidth);
}

getWidth = () => {
    const elem = this.elem.clientWidth;
    ...
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <SomeComponent
                ref={(elem) => this.elem = elem}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
...
```

As this application renders server-side initially, then the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method does not run, hence, the `getWidth` function does not run and the event listener is not added to the window object. How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean it "renders server-side"? What are you using to accomplish this?

Comment: It is rendered server-side using Node. Then once the first page is downloaded React takes over. However, before React takes over, the componentDidMount lifecycle method will not run, and I need it to run immediately.

Comment: what is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html):

> If you call ReactDOM.render() on a node that already has this
>   server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event
>   handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load
>   experience.

Comment: Does this apply to `window` events and not just click event of components?

Comment: I have no idea, have you tested it?